# Build with Heroku.yml fails with unknown error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a NodeJS webapp to Heroku using heroku.yml file, but it fails without useful information.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . ./

RUN npm install --dev

# Needed for webpack client.json
RUN mkdir -p /app/public/build/


ENV NODE_ENV=production

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

heroku.yml:

```
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql
    as: DATABASE

build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile

release:
  # Run database migrations
  command:
    image: web
    command: npm run migrate up


# run: This is executed from the Dockerfile so not necessary here
```

The logs:

```
Kims-MacBook-Pro-401:stock-dd kimgysen$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 22, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 2.64 KiB | 1.32 MiB/s, done.
Total 22 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: === Fetching app code
remote: 
remote: =!= Unknown error
```

The build hangs here. In the Heroku activities build log I  see the same error:

```
=== Fetching app code
=!= Unknown error
```

Probably something obvious is wrong, but there is no useful info to go on. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using the Yaml array syntax for the `command` entry? The docs don't specify it, but I remember seeing strange behavior when using that feature. (IIRC, it's an array but it will only run the first entry.)

Comment: Didn't try that, but the problem happens already earlier when building the  image. It should start building the image first. It is strange, if I  try to `heroku git:clone -a <project>` it complains about the project being empty. It's as if something is corrupted in that remote git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Heroku was struggling with either empty lines, comments or whitespaces at the start of the file.
After removing these, it was fine.

There was also a wrong format here:

```
release:
  command:
    image: web
    command: npm run migrate up
```

Which had to be:

```
release:
  command:
    - npm run migrate up
  image: web
```